# Sphinx warning preload: failed to open

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I installed sphinx search service.
For creating indexes I use next command:

> sudo searchd -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf

After get warning message in terminal:

> using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'... listening on
>   127.0.0.1:3322 precaching index 'medicalfacilities' WARNING: index 'medicalfacilities': preload: failed to open
>   /var/data/sphinx/medicalfacilities.sph: No such file or directory; NOT
>   SERVING precaching index 'article_index'

Also tried to stop sphinx:

> searchd --stop

and exicute command:

> indexer --config /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf --rotate --all

It gave me message:

> using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'... indexing index
>   'medicalfacilities'... FATAL: failed to open
>   /var/data/sphinx/medicalfacilities.tmp.spl: No such file or directory,
>   will not index. Try --rotate option.

Please, explain me, why sphinx does not create indexes file? How fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> failed to open /var/data/sphinx/medicalfacilities.tmp.spl: No such file or directory

suggests that the folder `/var/data/sphinx/` does not exist. Create it :)

Comment: Just simply :) Thanks

Comment: In Manticore just don't use `/var/lib/manticore/data/` dir. Use `/var/lib/manticore/` dir.