# WARNING: index 'index': preload: failed to open .sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING

Tags: sphinx

I have deleted data from ~/sphinx/data/ folder. And, came back to run indexer but suddenly I started getting below error

```
WARNING: index 'fwdb_latest_search_results': preload: failed to open d:/wamp/www/FWv2/sphinx/data/fwdb_latest_search_results.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
```

Please let me know how to fix this.
I tried this way but didn't work.

[Sphinx warning preload: failed to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407708/sphinx-warning-preload-failed-to-open)

Comment: That message comes from `searchd` - not indexer. Means it cant open the index files to be able to 'serve' them. ... but you already mentioned had deleted the index files!

Comment: I think it gets recreated on rotate command but nopes

Comment: Yes, the index should be (re)created via 'rotate' - providing 1) you are actully calling indexer on that particular index, and 2) its not producing errors, and failing!